# std::sort algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

`std::sort` does sorting based on the `operator<`.

Now consider this class:

```
class Foo
{
private:
     int m_x;
public:
     Foo()
     {
          m_x = 0;
     };
     Foo(int a)
     {
          m_x = a;
     }
     bool operator<(const Foo &right) const
     {
          return m_x < right.m_x;
     };
     void Set( int a ) { m_x = a; };
     int Get() { return m_x; };
};

std::vector<Foo> myVec;

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
     myVec.push_back( Foo() );
myVec.at( 5 ).Set( 2 );
myVec.at( 2 ).Set( 3 );

std::sort( myVec.begin(), myVec.end() );
```

1. How will the elements be positioned in the resulting sorting vector?
2. I need to do something like this:

   ```
   int counter = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++ )
   {
        if( myVec.at( i++ ).Get() == myVec.at( i ) )
        {
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // assign some variable some value
        }
        // perform some calculation (I have multiple elements with the same value)
   }
   ```

Will there be a possibility of using iterators in this case? Is there a better algorithm to do that?

[EDIT]

Here is what I am trying to do.
Let's say I have a football team. It has 10 players. For every player there are bunch of technical/tactical values that can be considered either during the training or during the game.
So, all this is stored like this:

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<Foo>> score;
```

Now initially when the game starts all those values are 0. Now when player 5 do pass forward the value of the score["Player5Name] will become 1, but all other will stay 0.
At the end of the training those values will become sorted for each player and depending on whose player have bigger value the main scoring system will be updated.
So if player 5 has 100 passes forward and this value is the biggest one and nobody else has it than this player gets assigned the value of 10.
If players 3, 7 and 9 has 90 passes and it's second place then the calculation is (9+8+7)/3
And so forth.
The Foo class has another std::string member that describe what the player did so that the vector can be sorted by appropriate action.

I hope this clarifies what I am trying to do better.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Regarding your first question, `Foo::m_x` is assigned 0 by default. With only two elements set to non-zero, both of those will be at the *end* of an ascending sort. I.e. all those 0-Foo objects will precede them. Was it your intention to pass `Foo(i)` to that `push_back() loop ?

Comment: `if( myVec.at( i++ ).Get() == myVec.at( i ) )` -- You don't want to do that, because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Regarding a better algorithm, if you're interested in *consecutive* pairs, such an iterator-basd algorithm already exists in the standard library; [`std::adjacent_find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find). Used properly in a loop, it will do precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: @WhozCraig, well it goes like this: initially m_x are all 0's. But then some values are increased and the vector is sorted. Then the vector is processed. Depending whether there is the same value or different values the processing is different.

Comment: If that is the case, a [`std::multiset<Foo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) may be a better fit for what you're doing, and should be considered. You could/would only add the items as you need to. It would still allow for multiple instances and would be naturally sorted to ensure all instances of a given key are iterated consecutively. Most important, it would only have *real instances and not a bunch of '0' placeholders. Just thinking of options for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thank you. Problem is I don't need a placeholder, I need a real 0. Please read the edit of the OP and hopefully it will explain what I'm trying to do better.

Answer (score 0):

The array will be sorted as `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3]`, since you define the comparison operator on the `x` variable.

Regarding the second code snippet, it looks like you're trying to process multiple instances of the same element somehow. You usually don't want to increment a variable while you're using it again in the same statement. Try something like:

```
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < myVec.size(); i ++) {
    if (myVec[i - 1].Get() == myVec[i].Get()) {
        counter ++;
        continue;
    }
    //the else clause is redundant, as you already have a continue above
    //process the multiple variables
}
//process the last variable
```

Comment: jma127, It's not multiple instances of the same element. It's 10 elements, they are different but the value might be the same. So, if there is an elements with the same value I count them and process all of them based on the number of those elements.